# Can I Put Dom elements on phaser game window?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, phaser-framework

I have a situation where I need to drag an image from list of image on HTML page to the Phaser game window.

What i was trying to achieve here is putting `<li></li>` element of HTML with image list on phaser game window and then performing drag drom functionality on that image list.

Does anyone have any idea? any sample code or any relative link would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I place use HTML elements in conjunction with Phaser's Canvas all the time - it's very useful for user interfaces. Just create a div that will contain your HTML elements and absolutely position them over the canvas. Assuming your canvas is taking up the full page -

```
<div id="ui"><li>Your li or whatever</li></div>
```

```
#ui {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```